# Assign random nubers to a zero matrix

Tags: python

I can't run this:

```
import pprint
import random

linii = int(input("Introdu nr de linii: "))
coloane = int(input("Introdu nr de coloane:  "))

m = [[0 for i in range(linii)] for i in range(coloane)]

for i in range(linii):
    for j in range(coloane):
        m[i][j] = random.randint(1, 9999)

pprint.pprint(m)
```

This is the error
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:", line 11, in 
m[i][j] = random.randint(1, 9999)
IndexError: list assignment index out of range

Can you help me?

Comment: Switch `coloane` and `linii` In your loops. I.e. `for i in range(linii)` becomes `for i in range(coloane)` and `for j in range(coloane)` becomes `for j in range(linii)` (although I don't understand that language..)

Comment: Why first assign `0` and then overwrite? You could move `random.randint(1, 9999)` directly into the list comprehension?

Answer (score 0):

```
[[0 for i in range(linii)] for i in range(coloane)]
```

will make a matrix with `coloane` rows and `linii` columns as `[0 for i in range(linii)]` (each row) will be repeated for `coloane` times and `i` (each column) will be repeated for `linii` times

Example the following code produce the following output

```
l = [[0 for i in range(2)] for j in range(3)]

# output 
>>> l
[[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Alternative

You could use numpy to do this quickly as well, without any loops.

```
import pprint
import numpy

linii = int(input("Introdu nr de linii: "))
coloane = int(input("Introdu nr de coloane:  "))

m = np.random.randint(1,9999, (linii, coloane))  #<-----

pprint.pprint(m)
```

```
Introdu nr de linii: 4
Introdu nr de coloane:  5
[[8342, 4497, 4767, 4890, 5685],
 [115, 4045, 9906, 7124, 8472],
 [4809, 4123, 7765, 3854, 3520],
 [4719, 89, 2895, 9002, 3200]]
```